# How to change tab background color when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change tab background color while click and active that tab..and font color also want change while clicking tab

`My fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/fDk3z/4/

Please any one help!

Thanks for advance....

Answer (score 2):

Add this css

**CSS**

```
.hownav .tabrow li.selected1{background:#ccc}
.hownav .tabrow li.selected1 a{color:#fff}
```

Answer (score 1):

set background `.selected1` to the color you want.

```
.tabrow li.selected1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.tabrow li.selected1 a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fDk3z/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript code for active tab color change.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("li").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("li").css("background-color","");
            $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can do it with css, why using a script?

Comment: But css make this easier and lighter! :)

Comment: Okay so go your way but one think is that if you choose css then you have to add class in your stylesheet and jquery also so according to my opinion jquery is batter.